# How to automatically remove console.logs() in development?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, eslint

### The Problem

Trying to lint an old React application that has 30+ `console.logs()` throughout the code base. I setup a linter and code formatter, ESLint and Prettier respectively.

This setup works great and it shows me where the `console.logs()` are in the source. But, the `--fix` flag for ESLint does not remove the logs. Is there any way to automatically remove `console.logs()`? I've seen articles on how to do this via webpack to prevent the logs from going into production, however, I would like to remove these earlier in a pre-commit or pre-push hook for instance.

### What I've Tried

I tried setting up a script using `gulp-strip-debug`. It fails with an assertion error. When I changed the src path from `'./src/**.js'` to `'./**.js'` I do not get the assertion error but nothing happens.

> Learned about this from Jun711 blog. The ["How to remove console log from your JavaScript files programmatically?"](https://jun711.github.io/web/how-to-remove-console-logs-programmatically/) blog post.

**Gulpfile**

`gulpfile.js`: root of project directory

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');
gulp.task(
  'strip-debug',
  () =>
    gulp
      .src('./src/**.js') // input file path
      .pipe(stripDebug()) // execute gulp-strip-debug
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./')) // output file path
);
```

**Package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "end-the-pandemic",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "shelter-in-place": "11.5.20",
    "stay-home": "11.5.21",
    "who-is-still-voting-for-trump": "11.3.20", 
    "seriously-why": "2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "lint": "eslint '*/**/*.js' --quiet --fix",
    "clean": "gulp strip-debug",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },
...
```

**Terminal**

`yarn clean`

Output

```sh
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
```

Obviously, I could have done a search and deleted most of them manually with the time I spent writing this question but for future reference, is there anyway to do this with a command? I would like to put `yarn clean` in a pre-commit hook if possible.

Comment: Post all of your gulpfile.js if possible - that is a common gulp error message.  Secondly, `'./**.js'` isn't what you want - go with `'./**/*.js'` there is a big difference.

Comment: That is all of my gulp file. :) Lol am I missing something? I will try the path you provided. @Mark

Answer (score 4):

You could make this trick it would be good in this case

```
if (env === 'production') {
    console.log = function () {};
}
```

this will overwrite the real `log` function into an empty one

> make sure you add it at the top of your react app

### Another solution

there is a package called `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console` could help you
after installing it from `npm`

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-remove-console
```

after installing create a `.babelrc` file in your project root `dir`
and add this line to it

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
}
```

Comment: The babel plugin happens on build? When does that execute I guess is my question. I can't run a script for that right? It just happens when the source is compiled?

Comment: i didn't try this plugin before but it looks that would work after compiling

Comment: Okay cool. I upvoted. Not exactly what I was looking for but I think it's still valuable and I added it to the app Thank you :)